# Warning message display when try to log in to my website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have not take care of my site for couple months. Recently, I want to update my Wordpress and Themes. However, when I try to login `www.beatyourbuy.com/wp-admin`. It give me below message. First of all, I am not a IT expert, have limited knowledge of IT. Would really appreciate someone can help me about this.

The error message show as below *(forgive my poor English)*:

```
Warning: include(/home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/includes/classes/main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php on line 15

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/includes/templates/functions/required/shipping_required.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php on line 27

Warning: include(/home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/includes/templates/functions/woocm_editing_wrapper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php on line 28
```

There are more when you go to main page on www.beatyourbuy.com:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wccs_positioning() in /home/fredyu/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php on line 75
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory there. It's looking for files that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the WordPress update has caused a problem with the Woocommerce Checkout Manager plugin.

To correct this, you must disable the offending plugin `woocommerce-checkout-manager`.

This will require you to have FTP access to your site.  Once login via FTP , browse to the plugin directory `wp-content/plugins/` and rename the folder `woocommerce-checkout-manager` to `woocommerce-checkout-manager-disable`.

You should now be able to log into the WordPress admin page and the Woocommerce Checkout Manager plugin will be deactivated.

Going only with what you have written, as a general rule it is advisable to update all plugins prior to a WordPress core update.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - You added this comment to another answer and not to the OP's question.  I am in the same boat as you, an answer with not acceptance.